# Is buffalo milk proper for baby cow?

Tags: diet, cows

I have a very young cow, about a month old. Unfortunately her mother has died.

I have two buffaloes. Will it be proper to feed the baby cow buffalo milk or should I buy cow milk from outside?

Comment: I suspect that biology.se may be a better place to get an answer on this one.

Comment: If "is giving cow milk to cat" within scope, I can't see how this one falls under biology

Comment: It's less about scope and more about where you're more likely to find the expertise.